# Separator line in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, separator

I'd like to add a simple separator line in an aspx web form.

Does anyone know how? It sounds easy enough, but still I can't manage to find
how to do it..

10x!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A horizontal rule `<hr />` ?

Comment: Yes, I could of just wrote <hr /> ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nisi arcu, rutrum vel dignissim ac, elementum eu ligula. Mauris faucibus mi sit amet lectus consequat ut lacinia quam fermentum. Donec urna massa, porttitor ac blandit ut, mattis in risus. Ut eget nunc imperdiet nisi ultricies gravida. Integer suscipit ultrices elit, id elementum diam pharetra semper. Nullam tincidunt, tellus id tincidunt sodales, libero sapien porttitor ligula, rhoncus rhoncus eros mauris vel arcu. Proin ullamcorper tellus et purus adipiscing id luctus purus lacinia. Quisque lobortis, enim nec mattis adipiscing, arcu ante tempus eros, vitae sodales nulla urna eget sapien. Cras dui risus, eleifend molestie vulputate eu, varius ut libero. Vivamus consectetur dapibus adipiscing. Cras porta pulvinar felis. Praesent quis velit massa, non interdum neque. Quisque metus quam, tincidunt eu iaculis quis, auctor sed justo.
<hr/>
Nam vitae dui ipsum, id varius urna. Vivamus consequat auctor neque, ac vulputate tellus luctus sit amet. Maecenas vitae libero libero. Nulla et lacus in ante placerat ullamcorper. Pellentesque a erat sapien, convallis rutrum est. In luctus magna a lorem lobortis vel malesuada turpis dictum. Nam condimentum nunc in nunc tincidunt tincidunt. Etiam iaculis lectus at urna faucibus quis facilisis enim imperdiet. Phasellus sit amet viverra nisi. Cras tincidunt enim vel velit cursus elementum. Fusce sodales odio ac erat tincidunt ullamcorper tempor libero interdum. Curabitur a eros ligula. Phasellus sollicitudin dolor cursus lorem porttitor mollis. Nulla non sapien odio, et consectetur nisl. Curabitur convallis bibendum lacus eleifend imperdiet.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control its thickness and color, use a style:

```
<div style="border-top:1px solid red;"/>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a div for a separator. Just apply styling to the <hr />.